# Like/Dislike System with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

(Please find my solution in my answer post below)

hope you're doing good. My question today is about a like/dislike simple system with nodeJs, and the data is on MongoDB.

#### What's your situation?

1. I've been given the realization of the back-end of an API. The front-end is already done and not to be touched.
2. The API purpose is to allow people to post spicy sauces with a selection of parameters. Each user must be logged in to perform any action ! At this dev stage, any refresh performed on any page sends the user straight back to the login page.
3. I'am at the very last task I need to achieve which is : implementing a route for a "like/dislike" simple system. This system has these settings :

- if the user clicks on the "thumb up", the front-end sends a "1" number value (hereafter called 'likeStatus')
- if the user clicks on the "thumb down", the front-end sends a "-1" like Status
- if the user un-clicks their like/dislike, the front-end sends a "0" likeStatus
- when the user has clicked on either thumb, the user's ID is stocked in one of the two arrays built in the object model : usersLiked or usersDisliked depending on the choice made by the user. Note that both arrays are included in the 'sauce' model, so they are not to be found in the user model.
- on the front-end side, when the user clicks on any thumb, the other one is greyed, preventing them to click on it. The user must un-click their initial choice to be able to choose another one.

#### What is your problem?

My problem is that I cannot track the un-clicks of the user, when they go back from "1" or "-1" to "0(zero)". And that is because I don't know how to check where the user was before it went back to zero. It's important to me to be sure to delete him from the right array and to decrement the right counter and not both or the wrong one.

After having tried what I describe below, I'm looking for a way to check :

- where was the userId stocked, in which array (userLiked or userDisliked)

or

- what was the user's last likeStatus (1 or -1)

#### what did you try so far?

I wanted to use a chain of if/else to both check the likeStatus and search both the arrays usersLiked and usersDisliked to see if the userId (here called 'liker') were in there. If it was in the usersLiked, then I could decrement the likes counter and the opposite if the id were in userDisliked.
But both arrays are seen as "undefined" and so cannot be read.

#### Show us your code

There is the entire code of the like/unlike route that I've built so far :

```
exports.likeSauce = (req,res,next) =>{  
  const liker = req.body.userId;
  let likeStatus = req.body.like;
  let usersLiked = req.body.usersLiked;
  let usersDisliked = req.body.usersDisliked;
  if(likeStatus===1){
    sauce.updateOne({_id:req.params.id}, {$inc:{likes:+1},$push:{usersLiked:liker}})
      .then(()=>res.status(201).json({message:'you liked this sauce'}))
      .catch(error=>res.status(400).json({error}))
  } else if (likeStatus===-1) {
      sauce.updateOne({_id:req.params.id}, {$inc:{dislikes:+1},$pull:{usersLiked:liker},$push:{usersDisliked:liker}})
      .then(()=>res.status(201).json({message:'you disliked this sauce'}))
      .catch(error=>res.status(400).json({error}))
  } else if(likeStatus===0){
    if(usersLiked.includes(liker)){
      sauce.updateOne({_id: req.params.id}, { $inc: { likes: -1}, $pull: { usersLiked:liker}})
    } else if (usersDisliked.includes(liker)){
      sauce.updateOne({_id: req.params.id}, { $inc: { dislikes: -1}, $pull: { usersDisliked:liker}})
    }
  }
}
```

#### Anything else that might be helpful?

here is the 'sauce' model with both the arrays at the end of it:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const sauceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {type:String},
  name: {type:String, required:true},
  manufacturer:{type:String, required:true},
  description:{type:String, required:true},
  mainPepper: {type:String, required:true},
  imageUrl:{type:String, required:true},
  heat: {type:Number, required:true},
  likes: {type:Number},
  dislikes : {type:Number},
  usersLiked : {type:["String <userId>"]},
  usersDisliked: {type:["String <userId>"]},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('sauce', sauceSchema);
```

this question echoes to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71807385/like-dislike-system-with-mongodb) but the solution there provided didn't help me much (same situation by the way)

There you are, I thank you for reading my long post and for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: In your `likeSauce` route, why isn't the request sending you the sauce whose like status is being modified?  I don't see how you can possibly do the right thing without knowing which sauce is being liked?

Comment: And why are `req.body.usersLiked` and `req.body.usersDisliked` coming from the request?  Is there some middleware that is setting those.  They certainly shouldn't be coming from the client.  Can you show EXACTLY what data is coming from the client?

Comment: This code also looks like it may be vulnerable to race conditions because you have an array of data from the database sitting in memory across an asynchronous operation (which gives other requests a chance to run and conflict with or overwrite your intentions.

Comment: Hey @jfriend00, thanks for your comments, but I find myself a bit at unease to answer you. First point, we're already on a particular sauce page, so the route just pick the id of the sauce. Second point, they gave us the arrays to insert in the model, but no middleware to set them I think. You ask for what the Client sends ? well a console.log(req.body) returns an object with userId and 1 or 0 or -1.Third point : interesting I'll check that out.

Comment: Where does the array come from?  You show it coming from `req.body` which typically means it comes from the client.  If so, that's a really bad design.  The client should never be managing the array.  The client should send you a single modification it wants to make to the array and you update the database accordingly by merging their incremental modification with the current data from the database.

Comment: @jfriend00, as far as I know the arrays have been implemented in the model that you find at the end of my OP, but beyond that my session skimming through the front folder didn't return anything regarding those arrays. And nothing else in the back either

Comment: OK, now I see that perhaps the sauceID is coming from `req.params.id` which is parsed from the URL.  I understand that one now.  You do need to know where the arrays come from through in order to make sure this isn't setting up a bad design or buggy implementation subject to race conditions.

Comment: I'm asking where `req.body.usersLiked` and `req.body.usersDisliked` come from?

Comment: I can tell you that those arrays only appear twice in the whole project : first in the sauce model file reproduced in the OP and second in the route here discussed. So only in the back-end of the project, not in the front, not at all

Comment: Well, they don't magically appear out of thin air.  You must be missing something that is populating them, either in middleware or in the client.

Comment: I'll check that out and come back when I find the solution. thanks again for all your comments so far :-)

Comment: Perhaps some middleware is loading the whole sauce document and those fields aren't named specifically in that code, but are assigned to `req.body` in the middleware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250059/discussion-between-elradsoldier-and-jfriend00).

Comment: I posted the code abstract in the chatroom linked above. It's in that create sauce route that the arrays are created I guess ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my own problem and thought I might share it with you all. It's not a very elegant nor  perfectly dynamic solution but it has, at least, helped me to solve my problem. Ideally I would have liked to dynamically increment the likes and dislikes counters by applying the `usersLiked` and `usersDisliked` `array.length` but well  if someone has an idea, it will be welcome. Without further ado, here's the code:

```js
exports.likeSauce = (req, res, next) => {  
  const liker = req.body.userId;
  let likeStatus = req.body.like;
  sauce.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
    .then((votedSauce) => {  
      if (likeStatus === 1) {
        sauce.updateOne({ _id:req.params.id }, { $push: { usersLiked: liker }, $inc: { likes:1 }})
          .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'you liked this sauce' }))
          .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }))
      } else if (likeStatus === -1) {
        sauce.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { $inc: { dislikes: 1 }, $push: { usersDisliked: liker }})
          .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'you disliked this sauce' }))
          .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }))
      } else if (likeStatus === 0) {
        if (votedSauce.usersLiked.includes(liker)) {
          sauce.update({ _id: req.params.id }, { $inc: { likes:  -1 }, $pull: { usersLiked: liker }})
            .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message:'you un-liked this sauce' }))
            .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }))
          } else if (votedSauce.usersDisliked.includes(liker)) {
            sauce.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { $inc: { dislikes: -1 }, $pull: { usersDisliked: liker }})
            .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message:'you un-disliked this sauce' }))
            .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }))
          }
      }
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }))
};
```